# How to Remove this battery symbol of head in Android 4.0.4 device Sony Xperia MT27i?

Tags: notification-bar, sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

0.4 device **Sony Xperia MT27i** For development use.
I describe one screen the here, and display my question:

[image: Image Screen with red mark]
<sup>Image Screen with red mark (click image to enlarge)</sup>

I want to remove the icon from my device screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its power saving symbol and you have to disable from Setting  for remove symbol.